# Javascript split the characters and alphanumeric value

Tags: javascript

I have a string with HTML tags and free texts

```
let paragraph = ` <p class="card-text" style="font-weight: 100">This is 
  image 1. </p>`
```

I am trying to separate the punctuations and spaces and want to display just the following

```
[p, class, card-text, style, font-weight, 100, this, is image 1, p]
```

I tried to use the following approach

```
let elements = paragraph.split(" ")
```

But got

```
["", "<p", "class="card-text"", "style="font-weight:", "100">This", "is", "↵", "", "", "", "", "", "image", "1.", "</p>"]
```

is there any other way than split?

Thank you

Comment: Whatever your point is, I think you're probably going about it in a way that's going to lead to you ramming your head against a wall. It's awful to parse HTML manually. Especially because you can nest Nodes. Why are you doing this? What is the purpose? I'm sure we can find you a better way.

Comment: You can split it on ">", grab element [1]. Then split that on "<", grab element [0], then split the rest on space.

Comment: Or you can turn it into a document fragment, grab the innerText, then split that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match words, you could use a regular expression that matches word characters:

```js
let paragraph = `<p class="card-text" style="font-weight: 100">This is 
  image 1. </p>`

let result = paragraph.match(/\w+/g)

console.log(result)
```